# Cycles getting black shaded areas of emission / transparent shaded faces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency

I have a terrain mesh that I have shaded using a combination of emission shader and transparent shader. The issues is when I view the model from any angle where there would overlap from itself, for example both sides of a mountain are visible due to the transparency. The back sides appear to be black. I have disabled shadow rays for the object but it does not help. Attached is a pic of the issue and shader I am using.
[image: Black backfaces]
[image: Shader being used]

Comment: Increase the number of transparent bounces

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.